# RubyMine show hidden folders

Tags: rubymine, jetbrains-ide

How do you show hidden folders in RubyMine? I found the shortcut Alt + H by searching in help but it doesn't work. I have a hidden file in one of my folders inside my project, but when I select that folder in the project column and pres Alt + H nothing happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you mean by hidden files? the ones with 'hidden' attributes? Hidden files are shown in the Project toolwindow. Please make sure that your hidden file is not added to ignored files in `Settings (Preferences) | Editor | File Types`, `Ignore files and folders` list

Comment: Well I, for example, install my gemfiles into PREJECT_NAME/.bundle. I then realized that I wanted to look at one of the gems but couldnt find the folder PROJECT_NAME/.bundle since it is hidden. I can find it in the terminal but am unable to find it through RubyMine.
EDIT: The file was in the ignore list, thank you for pointing that out :)